# c# - Query is never null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

I'm new to Programming and C# especially so I'm trying to create a small app connected to sql server that lets me save clients name, phones and address. I'm facing one problem that is my "Checking data if already exists" is always telling that it's not null and can't save. I'd appreciate some help. I know it's very noob and sorry for bothering.

```
      //Create and Open Connection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KDC-LP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ClientsDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        con.Open();

        //Finding if data already exists
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from clients where name = @name or phone1 in (@phone1, @phone2, @phone3) ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textbox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone1", textbox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone2", textbox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone3", textbox4.Text);            
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Saving or not ?
        MessageBoxResult msg = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save the new data", " Save", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        switch (msg)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:

                if (reader != null) //Name, Phones already exists
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    MessageBoxResult notsaved = MessageBox.Show("Data already exists please check", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Saving
                    reader.Close();
                    SqlCommand cmdins = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Clients (name,phone1,phone2,phone3,address) Values ('" + textbox1.Text + "', '" + textbox2.Text + "', '" + textbox3.Text + "', '" + textbox4.Text + "', '" + textbox5.Text + "')", con);
                    cmdins.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    textbox1.Clear();
                    textbox2.Clear();
                    textbox3.Clear();
                    textbox4.Clear();
                    textbox5.Clear();
                    MessageBoxResult saved = MessageBox.Show("Data is Saved", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
                break;

                //Not Saving
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                {
                    MessageBoxResult msgno = MessageBox.Show("Data is not saved", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                }
                break;
        }

        //Closing Connection 
        con.Close();
```

Comment: You say `cmd.ExecuteReader();` which returns `SqlDataReader` always, thus the `reader` can't be `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The `HasRows` property tells you whether query returned rows or not, you need to use that:

```
            if (reader.HasRows) //Name, Phones already exists
            {
                reader.Close();
                MessageBoxResult notsaved = MessageBox.Show("Data already exists please check", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
```

Comment: so how to tell if the query is empty or not ? If the reader always return something how should I know if the query is empty or contain any data ?

Comment: `HasRows` is a boolean property, if it is _true_ it means query returned rows/records and result is not empty, if it is _false_ it means query returned no records and result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteReader` always returns a reader. If the query didn't find any data, a reader still will be returned. It just doesn't "contain" any data. So that is what you need to check for:

```
if (reader.HasRows) //Name, Phones already exists
```